# R remove duplicate rows keeping those with values

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with four columns: question, id, country and response. In the id column I have several duplicates. This is because they refer to the same question, but the responses are different in the sense that one of the duplicates has a value and the other is NA. Now I would like to remove the duplicates and keep those row where the response column has a value. Note that the value in my database are either numeric or character.

I have tried to use `distinct()` from the dplyr package. However, the problem is that it deletes always the first row / the first duplicate regardless what stands in the response column.

Here is my code:

`df1 %>% distinct(id, country, .keep_all = TRUE)`

The output I expect is that I am left with unique id rows (no duplicates are left) and that in the response column no information is lost. See the example below:

```
    #Initial data frame
    df1  <- read.table(text="question id  country response
                              X1    10  Belgium    40
                              X2    12  Austria    NA
                              X2_1  12  Austria    NEW
                              X4    17  USA        NA
                              X5    17  USA        5
                              X6    NA  Italy      61
                              X7    15  Spain      
                              X8    15  Spain      100", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`


    #Expected Output
    df1  <- read.table(text="question id  country response
                              X1    10  Belgium    40
                              X2_1  12  Austria    NEW
                              X5    17  USA        5
                              X6    NA  Italy      61
                              X8    15  Spain      100", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`
```

Comment: Either (a) sort your data (most sorts will put the NAs last so they will be the duplicates omited) or (b) just omit NAs, `na.omit(df1)`

Comment: delete `NA` rows in `response` ? `df1[!is.na(df1$response), ]`

Answer (score 11):

We can do an `arrange` to make sure the `NA` elements are arranged last and then take the `distinct` so that `distinct` takes the first non-duplicated rows based on the columns specified

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(id, country, is.na(response)) %>% 
   distinct(id, country, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

If we need to keep 'id's that `NA` without taking the `distinct` of those

```
df1 %>% 
   arrange(id, country, is.na(response)) %>% 
   group_by(id, country) %>%
   filter(row_number() == 1 | is.na(id))
```

---

For this example, even

```
df1[complete.cases(df1$response),]
```

In `tidyverse` syntax

```
df1 %>% 
    filter(complete.cases(response))
```

would work, but it may not work in the actual dataset

Comment: The dplyr version works perfectly, thank you! The second solution would not work in my actual dataset.

Comment: I just saw that one problem I am encountering is that I have some rows without id (they are blank), and these rows are also deleted using the dplyr approach because `distinct()` treats them as duplicates. Ideally I would like to have them in my dataset. Is there a way to address this in your approach above?

Comment: @user9660581  DId you meant the `NA` rows in `id`

Comment: @user9660581  Try the updated version `df1 %>% 
   arrange(id, country, is.na(response)) %>% 
   group_by(id, country) %>%
   filter(row_number() == 1 | is.na(id))`

Answer (score 3):

A base R solution could be the following.

```
i <- !(duplicated(df1$id) & duplicated(df1$id, fromLast = TRUE))
j <- !is.na(df1$response)
df1[i & j, ]  
#  question id country response
#1       X1 10 Belgium       40
#3     X2_1 12 Austria      NEW
#5       X5 17     USA        5
#6       X6 NA   Italy       61
#8       X8 15   Spain      100
```